# Obtain next "version" (.NET Regex)

Tags: c#, .net, regex, vb.net

I need to obtain from a string `version` (of maximum 3 chars like sql varchar(3), the "next version" with the following simple rule:

if its last chars constitutes a number, increment it, if it always fits max 3 chars, else, leave it as is.

Say "Hi1" => "Hi2", "H9" => "H10" but "xx9" will remain unchanged.

```
  Public Shared Function GetNextVersion(oldVersion As String) As String
    Dim newVersion As String = String.Empty
    If Regex.IsMatch(oldVersion, "?????") Then
      Return newVersion
    Else
      Return oldVersion
    End If
  End Function
```

Comment: This is fairly easy to write by following your description word by word ... Also I only see a need for using regex for splitting the string into an alphabetic and numeric part, not for matching.

Comment: For future reference please read the `homework` tag description

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be your regex, it will match anything with a gruop of letters followed by a group of numbers.

```
Public Dim regex As Regex = New Regex( _
      "^(?<prefix>.*?0*)(?<version>\d+)$", _
      RegexOptions.IgnoreCase _
        Or RegexOptions.CultureInvariant _
        Or RegexOptions.Compiled _
    )
```

It will contain two named capture groups, "prefix" which is the initial characters, and "version" which has your version.

Cast the version to an int, increment it, and return the new version number by concatenating the prefix and new version.

So, you'll end up with something like this

```
Public versionRegex As Regex = New Regex( _
   "^(?<prefix>.*?0*)(?<version>\d+)$", _
   RegexOptions.IgnoreCase _
     Or RegexOptions.CultureInvariant _
     Or RegexOptions.Compiled _
 )

Public Shared Function GetNextVersion(oldVersion As String) As String
    Dim matches = versionRegex.Matches(oldVersion)
    If (matches.Count <= 0) Then
        Return oldVersion
    End If

    Dim match = matches(0)
    Dim prefix = match.Groups.Item("prefix").Value
    Dim version = CInt(match.Groups.Item("version").Value)

    Return String.Format("{0}{1}", prefix, version + 1)
End Function
```

Comment: this does not work for "7x7", nor for "k*7"... also, but this is less important, any verification lenght is not done...

Comment: @serhio, How was I to know that was a valid version number?  Give us some examples, with input, and output

Comment: I provided some examples in the question. more examples: "7x7"=>"7x8", "1c"=>"1c", "11"=>"12", "*0" => "*1"

Comment: @serhio, Try it now, I updated the regex to `^(?<prefix>.*?)(?<version>\d+)$`, it will now return the version as the numbers at the right of the string, anything leading up to the last batch of numbers is considered the prefix.

Comment: @serhio, try it again, apparently i didn't past the regex properly in both spots

Comment: `(?<prefix>.*?)(?<number>\d+\Z)` works better! ;) for "7x7" by ex.

Comment: @serhio, you probably don't want the `\Z` as part of the capture group, I'd put it after the closing `)`, resulting in `(?<prefix>.*?)(?<number>\d+)\Z`

Comment: @serhio, You wouldn't see it, because it's a nonprinting character, however, a linefeed isn't part of a number, so don't capture it as part of a number.

Comment: I have one little "trouble", "x02" => "x3" but I want "x03"!

Comment: @serhio, I tucked a `0*` in the end of the prefix so that any 0s before the digits, are considered part of the prefix.  However, this will fail with x09, because it will change to x010 instead.  Trying to keep the 0 padding will be tricky if you want this to stay generic.

Answer (score 0):

I would not use regex
Regex is a parser and this is more logic than parsing
And for 3 chars regex is not faster than brute force

Strategy is performance.
Have to test for edge cases and there are a lot.
Do the cheap stuff first.
Clearly this is C#

Think got all the test cases.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(NewVer("H"));
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(NewVer("Hi"));
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(NewVer("Hii"));
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(NewVer("Hiii"));
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(NewVer("H1"));
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(NewVer("H9"));
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(NewVer("Hi1"));
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(NewVer("H19"));
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(NewVer("9"));
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(NewVer("09"));
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(NewVer("009"));
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(NewVer("7"));
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(NewVer("07"));
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(NewVer("27"));
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(NewVer("347"));
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(NewVer("19"));
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(NewVer("999"));
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(NewVer("998"));
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(NewVer("C99"));
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(NewVer("C08"));
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(NewVer("C09"));
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(NewVer("C11"));
    }

    public static string NewVer(string oldVer)
    {
        string newVer = oldVer.Trim();
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(newVer)) return oldVer;
        if (newVer.Length > 3) return oldVer;
        // at this point all code paths need char by postion
        // regex is not the appropriate tool
        Char[] chars = newVer.ToCharArray();
        if (!char.IsDigit(chars[chars.Length - 1])) return oldVer;
        byte lastDigit = byte.Parse(chars[chars.Length - 1].ToString());
        if (lastDigit != 9)
        {
            lastDigit++;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (byte i = 0; i < chars.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                sb.Append(chars[i]);
            }
            sb.Append(lastDigit.ToString());
            return sb.ToString();
        }
        // at this point the last char is 9  and lot of edge cases 
        if (chars.Length == 1) return (lastDigit + 1).ToString();
        if (char.IsDigit(chars[chars.Length - 2]))
        {
            if (chars.Length == 2) return ((byte.Parse(newVer)) + 1).ToString();
            byte nextToLastDigit = byte.Parse(chars[chars.Length - 2].ToString());
            if (nextToLastDigit == 9)
            {
                if (char.IsDigit(chars[0]))
                {
                    byte firstOfthree = byte.Parse(chars[0].ToString());
                    if (firstOfthree == 9) return oldVer; // edge case 999
                    // all three digtis and not 999
                    return ((byte.Parse(newVer)) + 1).ToString();
                }
                // have c99
                return oldVer;
            }
            else
            {
                //have c 1-8 9 
                return chars[0].ToString() + (10 * nextToLastDigit + lastDigit + 1).ToString();        
            }
        }
        // at this point have c9 or cc9
        if (chars.Length == 3) return oldVer;
        // at this point have c9
        return chars[0].ToString() + "10";
    }
```

Comment: ...oh my God!... how about the principle "readability first"?

Comment: It is written for performance.  Did you not get that is what I mean with "do the cheap stuff first"?   It is 15 lines long - what line(s) do you not follow?  Regex is overkill to get the last char test for digit.  Accepted solution does not test for length or 9.

Comment: @serhio you criticized my answer but it returns x03 from x02

Comment: Performance is not an issue when incresing a version number, unless you are increasing it one million times.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Don't know it is not going to be performed on million times.  If it is only done 100 times faster is not going to break it.

Comment: @serhio the accepted answer fails on 6 of these test cases.  How about "accuracy first"?